# Apply specific class on <li> element on click angular2

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I have a component like below,

```
<li >
    <a (click)="status='today'" class="search-dropdown-tabs-active">Today</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a (click)="status='tomorrow'">Tomorrow</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a (click)="status='weekend'">This weekend</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a (click)="status='thisweek'" >This week</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a (click)="status='nextweek'" >Next week</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a (click)="status='thismonth'" >This month</a>
</li>
```

How can i apply **`class="search-dropdown-tabs-active"`** on selected li element 
?

**App.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Output,EventEmitter} from '@angular/core'; 
@Component({
    moduleId:module.id,
    selector: 'calendar',
    templateUrl: './calendar.component.html'
})
export class CalendarComponent{
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how the angular2 docs say it should be done. Read more on the [docs page](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngClass).

```
<li [class.search-dropdown-tabs-active]="status === 'thismonth'">
    <a (click)="status='thismonth'" >This month</a>
</li>
```

Comment: No errors, but nothing happens . how can i apply the same style to <a> also?

Comment: any idea  here   ?

Comment: Uhh, haven't used angular2 in a while.. do any of the other answers work?  The style is simple - uness your a tags overwrite anything, the li's styling will be carried over. It's how CSS works.

Answer (score 2):

```
<ul>
    <li [class.search-dropdown-tabs-active]="status==='today'">
        <a (click)="status='today'" 
        >Today</a>
    </li>
    <li [class.search-dropdown-tabs-active]="status==='tomorrow'">
        <a (click)="status='tomorrow'" >Tomorrow</a>
    </li>
    <li [class.search-dropdown-tabs-active]="status=='weekend'">
        <a (click)="status='weekend'" >This weekend</a>
    </li>
    <li [class.search-dropdown-tabs-active]="status=='thisweek'">
        <a (click)="status='thisweek'" >This week</a>
    </li>
    <li [class.search-dropdown-tabs-active]="status=='nextweek'">
        <a (click)="status='nextweek'" >Next week</a>
    </li>
    <li [class.search-dropdown-tabs-active]="status=='thismonth'">
        <a (click)="status='thismonth'">This month</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Working [Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/PZL8cBpOUJlAc6wgeR36?p=preview)

Comment: how can i apply the same style to <a> also?

Answer (score 1):

```
<li [ngClass]="{'search-dropdown-tabs-active': status === 'today'}">
    <a (click)="status='today'">Today</a>
</li>
<li [ngClass]="{'search-dropdown-tabs-active': status === 'tomorrow'}">
    <a (click)="status='tomorrow'">Tomorrow</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<li [ngClass]="{'search-dropdown-tabs-active': isActivate("today")'}">
    <a (click)="activeTab = 'today'">Today</a>
</li>



isActivate(value : string) : boolean{
   return activeTab === value;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.